# Make 2D collider hit only specific 2D colliders without using collision layer mask

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, collision-detection

In my 2D game, there are some circles randomly placed and some balls.

Each ball has a reference to one of the circles and this circle will apply a force to pull the ball to its center.

However, balls can change their circle. When they do, they fly from the current circle to the new one.

My question is: how to let balls only collide with balls that belong to the same circle? In the moment that a ball changes its circle, I want it to ignore collisions with all the other balls, except the ones which belong to the same new circle.

---

As I can have a lot of circles, I don't think using collision layers will do the job, so is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go through [`Physics2D.IgnoreCollision`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.IgnoreCollision.html) and store your balls in separate collections.

Then

- initially run through them all once and make them ignore all other colliders
- then every time when entering a circle you run through the balls belonging to that circle and set `IgnoreCollision` to `false` for those.
- once you leave a circle you set them all back to `true`

Comment: I thought about that but let me build up a worst case scenario: suppose there were 1000 balls, do you know how bad it would be to ignore, say, 995 of them using this method?

Comment: @Daniel test and profile .. of course we can bring any approach to its knees ;) In my experience in general with 1000+ physics objects in Unity you will run into some performance issues anyway ;)

Comment: I'm asking because I don't know how unity physics engine handle these "exceptions" in collision detection behind the scenes. I had a similar problem some years ago when I found out `Physics2D.IgnoreCollision` and it was fine because I had only a few colliders to ignore, but I wanted to have a sense of how scalable it is.

Comment: unfortunately how exactly it works internally is not publicly available .. but I would imagine it is basically just some sort of Hashset with collider pairs and if a collision happens it is just an additional check whether this pair of colliders is known to be ignored .. I would expect some native dark sorcery that is more efficient than handling it on c# layer after event messages have already been triggered

Answer (score 1):

This technique solves the problem. You can put all colliders in default `IsTrigger` mode and temporarily turn off `IsTrigger` only when contacting balls of the same group (or the same color...). At that time similute physics will be done and `IsTrigger` will disable again while exiting Collision.

```cs
public class Ball : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int group;

    private Collider2D _collider2D;
    void Start() => _collider2D = GetComponent<Collider2D>();
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
     if (other.TryGetComponent(out Ball _b))
     {
         if (_b.group == group)
         {
             _collider2D.isTrigger = false;
         }
     }
    }
    private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        _collider2D.isTrigger = true;
    }
}
```

---

### Using Ignore Collision Once on Hit

As @derHugo mentioned above, `Physics2D.IgnoreCollision` can also be used. My new idea is to ignore it when you first impact with other groups. This solves the problem.

```cs
public int group;

private Collider2D _collider2D;
void Start()
{
    _collider2D = GetComponent<Collider2D>();
}

private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
{
     if (other.transform.TryGetComponent(out Ball _b))
     {
         if (_b.group != group)
         {
             Physics2D.IgnoreCollision(_collider2D, other.collider);
         }
     }
}
```

---

### Changing Groups

To change the groups, store the ignored colliders in a **HashSet** and with the `SetGroup` method below, in addition to refreshing (False Ignore) and clearing the hash Set, change value number as well.

```cs
private readonly HashSet<Collision2D> ignoredCollisions = new HashSet<Collision2D>();
     ...
     if (other.transform.TryGetComponent(out Ball _b))
     {
         if (_b.group != group)
         {
             ignoredCollisions.Add(other); // Add to Ignore Collisions..
             ...
         }
     }
```

```cs
private void SetGroup(int index)
{
    // Clear Ignore Collisions..
    foreach (var ignoredCollision in ignoredCollisions)
    {
        Physics2D.IgnoreCollision(_collider2D, ignoredCollision.collider, false);
    }
    ignoredCollisions.Clear();
    group = index;
}
```

Comment: I cannot stick to this solution because the circles are applying force to their balls the entire time, so if I turn every ball to a trigger, balls within the same circle would overlap and become a mess.

Comment: @Daniel I updated the answer. My idea is that once you encounter a collider from another group, Ignore it. In this way, only those that are needed are ignored and can maintain the maximum possible performance.

Comment: @KiynL I would expect the collision to already happen though -> you ignore them too late since they already collided and thereby influenced each other's movement .. I guess internally IgnoreCollision basically aready equals that sort of Hashset but probably a bit more efficient since handled in the native engine directly before event messages are even invoked

Comment: The first approach would need to be tested .. it might behave a bit strange as the disabled trigger will case a collision in the next physics update - at a moment where the objects potentially already overlap and therefore are stronger pushed away then you would expect from a normal collision .. probably the most promising alternative to plain `IgnoreCollision` though -> @Daniel you will still have to test and benchmark it I guess ;)

Comment: @derHugo I guessed that you meant to specify ignore collisions before the scene is loaded, but since the groups may be added or instantiated we'll run into them. It makes work order a bit difficult and complicated and needs a manager. Personally, I prefer the codes to be as compact as possible, so I suggested this hybrid approach.